# MYSQL: Issue with table querying

Tags: mysql, join

I am having an issue `queryin`g my table on `SQL`. I have two tables: `table 1 (8000 lines)` consists of one column containing only unique gene id's `(ex. HxC4233)` and `table 2 (20000 lines)` consisting of two columns containing similar gene id's to table one but there are duplicates (so not unique) with corresponding gene lengths. The issue is some of the same gene's had different isoforms `(ex. HxC4233_i1, HxC4233_i2)` with different lengths but I have trimmed my gene id's in both columns to only show this (HxC4233).

I want to create a query consisting of all the unique gene ids from table one with the gene corresponding gene lengths from table two. But I only wish to have the unique gene lengths and not all of them.

I have tried writing a command to obtain my desired output. But I am receiving all gene id's as my output. This is my command:

```
SELECT DISTINCT uniqgene_id, allgene_len
--> FROM table1 RIGHT JOIN table2 
--> ON allgene_id = uniqgene_id;
```

Is it possible to only output my unique gene id's and to only extract its corresponding gene length?

The `DISTINCT` command does not account for similar gene's with different lengths.

My desired output is to only have unique gene id's with its corresponding length.

My output should contain roughly 8000 lines.

Comment: I think adding `distinct` in select should work fine for you but I am not able to get the gist of this question so could you modify according to https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055/tips-for-asking-a-good-structured-query-language-sql-question

Comment: use left join not right join

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please read over [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and make sure to provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Especially for database-related questions, please provide example data inputs and your expected output (text, not images!) so we can easily see what you're trying to do. That being said, I believe `distinct` is what you're looking for. See https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-distinct.aspx for an example.

Comment: Hi @Marcinek I tried using LEFT JOIN as well but that didn't work either.

Comment: Hi @AnandVidvat I am really sorry! I am new to bioinformatics and I am really new to this! I apologize if my question wasn't as forthcoming, please let me know if there are any additional information I could provide that would make the my question easy to interpret.

Comment: HI @WOUNDEDStevenJones I am so sorry for the ambiguity in my question! I am new to bioinformatics and to SO, I appreciate the welcome! I tried using `DISTINCT` but it doesn't account for similar genes with different gene lengths.

Comment: You don't have to appologize to every one ;) Please post your output how you would expect the result to be.

Comment: Sure! :) @Marcinek

Comment: could you examples of table1 and tables 2 records and ideal output you are looking from those records ?

Comment: Hi @AnandVidvat I have provided an example of my ideal output but if you look at the query you can see that there are same genes but with different gene lengths. My question is, is there a way to only select one of the gene lengths.

Comment: But first yoiu must decide what value of gene length you want to display in cases where gene_id is duplicated in table2. Max or min? Or average? Then use group by gene_id and you get result of 8000 rows.

Comment: we can order according to lenght gene wise and pick the max lenght or even take average like @milda said

Comment: We could select the top hit so max length @Milda

Comment: YES! I would only like to select the max gene length @AnandVidvat

Comment: `SELECT uniqgene_id, MAX(allgene_len) FROM ... GROUP BY uniqgene_id`

Comment: @WOUNDEDStevenJones I think this is the correct answer. Please post ist as an answer.

Comment: Hi @WOUNDEDStevenJones I am trying to write this command out but I keep getting an error, would you mind posting this as a full answer please? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT DISTINCT allgene_id, MAX(allgene_len)
FROM table2 GROUP BY allgene_id;
```

It's not necessary to join the tables for this purpose.

Answer (score 1):

you can use the following query to pick records the highest gene_len for respective gene_id:

```
select uniqgene_id, allgene_len
from
(SELECT uniqgene_id, allgene_len, dense_rank() over (partition by t1.uniqgene_id order by allgene_len desc) as rnk
FROM table1 t1 left join t2
ON t1.allgene_id = t2.uniqgene_id)
where rnk = 1
group by 1,2;
```